# get blank node in binary search tree in php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, depth-first-search

I want to find out the blank node in binary search tree.
For this i have used recursion. Below are my code:

```
function getNullNode($catid){       
$sql        = "select * from `mlm_reg` where `key` ='".$catid."'";
$result     = mysql_query($sql);
$getnnum    = mysql_num_rows($result); 
        while($fetchCat = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            if(count($fetchCat) < 2){
                $newId = $catid;
                return $newId;  
            } else {
                getNullNode($fetchCat->mlm_id);
        } 
    } 
}
```

mlm_id is user id and key = refer id but it gave me blank value.
Note: Parent can create two child only.
Example: Suppose admin create two child a,b and if he want to add third child then it will added under b or c so for this i am searching null node or parent that have only 1 or 0 child and if b and c both have two/two child then it will be searching their.

But above code will no gave me parent id Can some one see this issue.
What i am doing wrong

Comment: you never capture the returned value anywhere, and what's the point of echo/exit/break? the break can never execute, and `echo` does output, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Then how to return value

Comment: I Want to find out first depth blank node or parent node which have child not more than one or may be zero

Comment: I got my issue  and resolved it thank you very much for taking your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNullNode($catid){   
$sql        = '';
$result     = '';
$getnnum    = '';
$fetchCat   = '';
$sql        = "select * from `mlm_reg` where `key` ='".$catid."'";
$result     = mysql_query($sql);
$getnnum    = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if($getnnum < 2){
    return $catid;
} else {
        while($fetchCat = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            return getNullNode($fetchCat->mlm_id);
        } 
 } 
}
```